# SSAS: Key not found error when deploying solution, but no error when individually processing cube/dimension

Tags: sql-server, ssas, teradata

So I have a dimension called "Branch" and a fact table called "Regional NAF".  Both have an attribute named REGION_CODE, and I'm using named queries in the DSV to pull in the right data for the dimension and fact table.  Both this dimension and fact table are part of a cube with a few other fact tables and dimensions.

When I process the cube separately, in full, it processes fine without any errors.

But when I go to deploy the solution onto SQL Server I get an error that the attribute key cannot be found.  Which is really odd, since the cube itself processed fine.

When I check the underlying queries for the particular value that can't be found, the value shows up in both the query for the Branch dimension as well as the query for the Regional NAF fact table.  So I'm at a loss for how to fix this.

Has anyone else ever encountered such an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out what was wrong.  Or at least, there wasn't anything wrong per se.  But I removed the affected dimension from the cube, saved the solution, closed it and re-opened it and then added back the dimension.

I guess it just needed to be jogged, perhaps there were some latent issues stored in memory / cache that were reset after removing the dimension and adding it back in.